# Ajax pass Null values to controller using model

Tags: javascript, c#, .net-core

I have a post request in .net core.  When I call it using AJAX, the method is hit, but all my attribute values are null.  There are many examples of fixing this around the web, but I can't seem to find one that works.  In fact, I have many POST requests in this project, and they all work fine, yet this one does not which leads me to believe I have something simple that I'm just not seeing.

Here is the simplified AJAX call:

```
    let questionChoiceData = {
    'QuestionID':'1',
    'ChoiceID':'0',
    'SurveyID':'1',     
    'ResponseText':'Did I work?',
    'DeleteFlag': '0'
};

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Create_Edit',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(questionChoiceData),
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Here is my controller code:

```
    [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
    [Route("[action]")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create_Edit([FromBody] Choice_Model v)
    {
        //Everything below was deleted for brevity sake. Just know that When I set a breakpoint, V shows the model with it's attributes, but no attribute values.

       
    }//Method
```

Here is my model class:

```
    public class Choice_Model
{
    string QuestionID { get; set; }
    string ChoiceID { get; set; }
    string SurveyID { get; set; }
    string ResponseText { get; set; }
    string DeleteFlag { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative way to send your data to your `Controller` method:

`AJAX`:

```
let questionChoiceData = {
'QuestionID':'1',
'ChoiceID':'0',
'SurveyID':'1',     
'ResponseText':'Did I work?',
'DeleteFlag': '0'
};

var json = {
   questionChoiceData: questionChoiceData
};


$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Create_Edit',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {'json': JSON.stringify(json)},
    success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
    console.log(error);
    }
});
```

`Controller`:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
[Route("[action]")]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create_Edit(string json)
{
   Root rootData = new Root();
   Choice_Model choice_model = new Choice_Model();
   if(!string.IsNotNullOrEmpty(json))
   {
     //Get the data here in your model
     rootData=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
     choice_model = rootData.questionChoiceData;
   }

}//Method
```

`Model`:

```
public class Choice_Model
{
    string QuestionID { get; set; }
    string ChoiceID { get; set; }
    string SurveyID { get; set; }
    string ResponseText { get; set; }
    string DeleteFlag { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
  public string json {get;set;}
  public Choice_Model questionChoiceData {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Still get the same result.  string json is null in the controller.

Comment: @Chris Did you remove `contentType: "application/json",` from the AJAX call ?

Comment: No I did not.  I missed that.  I just ran it again and that works. Thank You.